# kernel oops at double pointer dereference

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel

I am getting a NULL pointer dereference issue in linux kernel. Using addr2line on PC I am able to get the line number in code. But the line where this oops is occuring is a double pointer dereference.

```
eg. xx->yy->zz
```

Here we are dereferencing xx and xx->yy in one line.

```
addr2line -f -e vmlinux c03200f8
func
lmn/uva/hello.c:101

101: if(xx->yy->zz==hello)
```

So how to know which field is NULL xx or xx->yy?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You *check* it before you dereference the pointer? Like in `if (xx != NULL) { ... }`?

Comment: You can easily derive if it was the first or second dereference which caused havoc by disassembling the code around the EIP when the oops happened.

Comment: Put some asserts and yo'ull find out which one is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

In the kernel source tree there is scripts/decodecode. Once you feed it the oops you will human-readable assembly surrounding the crashing instruction.

You will have to analyze how it fits the source tree from there. It's a mandatory skill for anyone doing kernel programming and is not that hard to do most of the time. One easy shortcut is to check offsets of dereferenced fields and see how it relates to the crashing address.

Comment: yes you are right, I disassemble the vmlinux and went to the location of crash using PC. and after analyzing assembly code, I was able to find the exact pointer which was NULL. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In general, to avoid tese type of NULL pointer dereference, we use the style

```
  if (xx && xx->yy)
```

where, the dereference is only evaluated if `xx` is not NULL.

As per the short-circuit operator property, in this case, logical AND, the RHS operand is evaluated only if the LHS is evaluated to TRUE. So, for the above example,

- when `xx` is NULL, the dereference is prohibited.
- when `xx`is not NULL, the dereference takes place.

> *So how to know which field is NULL xx or xx->yy*

Break down the operations, put debug prints and run again if you want to know the NULL-ity  of a pointer. That's a generic advice.

Comment: I don't think this comment is sound. Slapping a null check is the typical wrong thing to do - most of the time the bug is that the pointer is null in the first place. The advice to split the expression is sometimes usable, but if the crash is not easily reproducible it is useless and no further hints were provided.

Comment: @employeeofthemonth `Slapping a null check is the typical wrong thing to do` care to elaborate? `most of the time the bug is that the pointer is null in the first place`..well that is what the check is for.

Comment: if the pointer must not be null and you change if (foo->bar) to if (foo && foo->bar), then you are attempting to paper over the bug. Sounds like exactly what you don't want to do. Note I don't mind adding a null check for *debugging* purposes.